# 8 - Drupal 8 hook into registration

Tags: drupal, hook, registration, drupal-8

When a user registers on my site, I want to take data out of a CSV file and inject it into the users profile.

However I am not able to hook into any hook like hook_user_register().

Anyone have tips ?

Answer (score 1):

many hooks for core entities in D8 has been unified into a standard set of entity hooks. In your case, the following would be a good one to use:

```
hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
```

You can read the doc at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8